# How can use @escaping for a func which used in didSet without using a reference type in Swift?

Tags: swift

This down code works just fine! As soon as I update testFunc, with '@escaping', it start make error about

> Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

```
struct TestType {

    var string: String {
        didSet(oldValue) {
            if (oldValue != string) {
  
                testFunc(string: string, result: { resultValue in
                    value = resultValue
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
   private(set) var value: String
 
}


func testFunc(string: String, result: (String) -> Void) {
    result(string + " updated!")
}
```

my goal is to be able use:

```
func testFunc(string: String, result: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    result(string + " updated!")
}
```

How can I solve the issue without using a reference type?

Comment: Why do want `testFunc` to take an escaping closure?  Do you need to set `value` asynchronously?

Comment: You simply can't do what you want to do with a `struct`.  You have to do something else to accomplish whatever the larger goal is.

Comment: As the code stands you have no need for @escaping since `self` is always present when the closure is called. So maybe you could describe a use case where `@escaping` is needed so it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I am looking to call some network process and it would be finished in future, I could solve my issue using a reference type, but I was interested to stay with value type if it is possible.

Comment: @codycode1478 I don’t know if you really didn’t understand the purpose of my questions or if there is some less than savory intent, so let me clarify that I have been programming for over 40 years, and have been using Swift since version 2.0.   I asked about what you were trying to accomplish in order to help you with your problem.

Comment: If you are going to make asynchronous calls then the code will work with `@escaping`.

Comment: @ChipJarred: The years does not matter when we do not know about one topic, we can always learn with others question no issue.

Comment: Person A posts, “When I put a round peg in this round hole, it fits, but when I try this square peg, it doesn’t. How can I make the square peg fit?”  Person B asks, “Why do you want to put a square peg into a round hole?”  Person A answers, “If you don’t understand square pegs, you can post a question.” 

Answer (score 1):

The problem with capturing mutating `self` in an `@escaping` closure in a `struct` is there are really only two choices in how Swift might theoretically attempt to do it.

The first is to capture a reference to the `struct`, but in many cases it lives on the stack.  Since the `@escaping` closure could be called later, that means writing to the position on the stack where `self` *was*, but likely isn't there anymore.  If that happens when the stack has shrunk, then you're writing to an address that is effectively unreachable by any other code.   If it happens when the stack has grown back (or larger), then you're likely stomping on unrelated data, possibly some function's return address.  If you're lucky the result will be that the program crashes.  If you're unlucky, it will silently do the wrong thing.

Another possible implementation is that Swift could capture a copy, which of course, could be safely written to, but would be inaccessible to any other code.  That's pretty pointless.

There is a third option Swift could do, which is it could box the struct (that is actually place it on the heap).  The problem is that nothing else would know about the heap location.  Again that's pretty pointless... and much much slower than allocating things on the stack.

If you really need to capture a mutating `self`, then you need `TestType` to be a `class`, but that means the rest of your code has to be written with reference semantics in mind.

Very likely, you need to think about whatever problem you're trying to solve in a different way.  Without knowing what that is, concrete solutions are impossible to suggest.